# Documentation Confusion

Tags: java, documentation, javadoc

I'm aspiring to be a software engineer, and I have been taking Computer Science courses for my degree college. While they teach us a lot of basics that are mostly easy to learn online, I also want to learn things such as common documentation conventions. I am sure that once I start taking courses like data structures they will teach a lot more about the processes leading up to the actually coding, which from what I understand are the most important parts. But I would like to start learning to do things properly early on, so I am trying to learn how to properly document my code.

I read the Wikipedia page about javadoc, and I tried to the best of my ability to replicate it. If anyone could provide any tips, pointers, or corrections to my documentation (or even the code) for this simple program I made just to practice documentation it would be much appreciated.

Transform.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

/**
 * @author      Nekko Rivera nekkoriv@gmail.com
 * @version     1.0
 * @since       2015-08-9
 */

public class Transform
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Gui theGui = new Gui();

    theGui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    theGui.setSize(600, 400);
    theGui.setResizable(false);
    theGui.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Gui.java

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

/**
 * @author      Nekko Rivera nekkoriv@gmail.com
 * @version     1.0
 * @since       2015-08-9
 */

public class Gui extends JFrame
{
/**
 * Generated by Eclipse
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7253493887106168112L;

/**
 * Name displayed on choiceBox for the user to select
 */
String[] portraitNames = {"Default", "Nurio", "Giada", "Triggah", "Spider"};

/**
 * The images that will be displayed upon selection
 */
Icon[] portraits = {new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("default.png")), new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("nurio.png")), new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Giada.png")),
        new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Triggah.png")), new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("spider.png"))};
/**
 * Allows the user to choose a portrait to display
 */
private JComboBox <String> choiceBox;

/**
 * Prompt for the user to change their appearance
 */
private JLabel promptLabel;

/**
 * Builds the window for the program
 */

/**
 * Displays the image chosen by the user
 */
private JLabel pictureLabel;

public Gui()
{
    super("Transform");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    drawGui();
}

/**
 * Draws the items onto the frame
 */
public void drawGui()
{
    pictureLabel = new JLabel(portraits[0]);
    promptLabel = new JLabel("Change appearance?");
    choiceBox = new JComboBox <String> (portraitNames);
    choiceBox.addItemListener(
            new ItemListener(){
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event)
                {
                    if(event.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                        pictureLabel.setIcon(portraits[choiceBox.getSelectedIndex()]);
                }
            }
            );

    add(pictureLabel);
    add(promptLabel);
    add(choiceBox);
    }
}
```

TLDR: is this documented correctly?

Comment: This is primarily opinion based... Each organization has their own documentation standards... Eg, putting author is required in a few cases but considered unnecessary/irrelevant/bad in others...

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. I thought it was the kind of thing that followed certain  widely excepted conventions.

Comment: [This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html) oracle article could be helpful.

Comment: If you are going to ask this (and it is largely opinion-based) then the code review site would be a better match maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not really a correct way to do documentation. What is good documentation depends on a lot of factors:

- the type of software (application, library, ...)
- the target group of the documentation (fellow programmers, end users, ...)
- conventions and tastes of your organisation/company
- etc.

Javadoc only generates a specific kind of documentation, namely API documentation for programmer's using the documented things (this may include your future self). In light of this some general pointers can be given:

- All classes, fields and methods visible from outside the package must be documented. This includes public classes and public and protected members (fields and methods). In your case, documentation for the public classes is missing.
- Whether private and package private items must also be documented depends on local customs. It is never wrong to document something.
- Useful Javadoc documentation for a method describes *what* a method does. It may also describe *how* the method does that, but in most cases that is not really interesting for the person using the method and can also be documented with non-Javadoc comments.
- Documentation should be precise. If there are pre-conditions, they should be mentioned (for example, something cannot be `null`, a number must be `>= 0`, etc). If there are specific corner cases, they should be mentioned. If a method has side-effect, this must be mentioned.

I hope these pointers are helpful.